# How do I set a bootstrap tab active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for a tabular interface. When I click on a tab, I am calling an function that hides and shows corresponding divs. This is my HTML Code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active" id="Chart1"><a href="#">Chart 1</a></li>
    <li  id="Chart2"><a href="#">Chart 2</a></li>
    <li  id="Chart3"><a href="#">Chart 3</a></li>
    <li  id="Chart4"><a href="#">Chart 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Based on that, I am using the following jquery to show and hide content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#pie").hide();
   $("#bar").hide();
   $("#Chart2").click(function(){
     $("#StateWise").hide();
     $("#pie").show();
   });
   $("#Chart3").click(function(){
       $("#StateWise").hide();
       $("#pie").hide();
       $("#bar").show();
   });
});
```

How can I do that on click, the active class changes to that particular tab?

Comment: Why are you not using http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs for your tabbed interface. if you use this you don't have to write your own js for this

Comment: Why don't you use the bootstrap way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
$("#Chart2").click(function() {

    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#StateWise").hide();
    $("#pie").show();

});

$("#Chart3").click(function() {

    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#StateWise").hide();
    $("#pie").hide();
    $("#bar").show();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap 4 then you can do like this.

```
$("#Chart1").click(function(){
 $('#Chart1').tab('show');
});
```

check the below reference

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabshow

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#Chart3").click(function(){
     $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('this').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#Chart1").click(function(){
     $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('this').addClass('active');
});
```